# Show that $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x+iy \to x$ is a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Show that $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x+iy) = x$ is a homomorphism mapping of the additive group of complex numbers on to the additive group of real numbers . Find $\ker f$.

Answer: By data $f(x+iy) = x$ so $f(a+ib) = a$
$$
 f((a+x)+i(y+b))=a+x. \\
 f(a+ib)+f(x+iy)=a+x.
$$
From this it is a homomorphism.

$\ker f = \{x+iy \in (\mathbb{C},+) \mid f(x+iy) = 0\}$.

Because $0$ is the identity of $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

Must I add more to this answer?

Answer (score 4):

$\ker f = \{ x+iy : x,y \in \mathbb R, x=0 \} = \{ iy : y \in \mathbb R \} $, the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 3):

Ihf's answer is where you should reach; I would add few intermediate steps to it: $f(x+iy) = 0 \implies x=0\implies \ker f = \{iy\mid y\in\Bbb R\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof that it is a homomorphism is correct. It would be nicer if you were more specific with the kernel. The kernel is the set of all i*y where y is a real number

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I wrote the kernel in general , I get it.